# What is the difference between multiple ifs and if-else in this case?

Tags: java

The program is supposed to stop looping at 1 but with multiple ifs, it continues to loop. I was able to complete the exercise using if-else but I am having trouble tracking and understanding the differences between multiple ifs and if-else here.

I am new here so thank you all in advance for the help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a starting value: ");
    int input = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print(input + ",");
    System.out.print(" ");

    while (input != 1) {
        if (input % 2 == 0) {
            input = input / 2;
            System.out.print(input + ",");
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        if (input % 2 == 1) { // replace with else
            input = 3 * input + 1;
            System.out.print(input + ",");
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }

    keyboard.close();
}
```

**Expected:** the program should stop at 1 (while check)

**Actual:** it continues to loop infinitely: 4 2 1 4 2 1 ....

Comment: you need to use else if.if (input % 2 == 1)

Comment: Each if condition is checked even though previous condition is passed in multiple if statements. But in if-else block if any one is passed others are skipped.

Comment: you can enter any integer. For example: Enter a starting value: 19

19, 58, 29, 88, 44, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1

Comment: Also typically you should not close the `Scanner` that opens `System.in`, if you close it you will be unable to open `System.in` again later in the program.  Better to suppress the warning for `System.in` and close streams that are not `System.in`.

Comment: @Nexevis I just started learning to programme so I will just leave it as in the class' instruction but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

Because the starting value is `4`, the first if-statement reduces it to `2`. On the next iteration of the loop, the first if-statement reduces it to `1`, but then the second if-statement sees that it's an odd number and multiplies it by `3` and adds `1`.

To fix this issue, your second if-statement needs to be replaced with `else`, as there are only two possible conditions:

```
if (input % 2 == 0) {
    input = input / 2;
} else {
    input = 3 * input + 1;
}

System.out.print(input + ", ");
```

This will make it so that, if the first if-statement is executed, then the second one won't be.

Comment: Thank you, Jacob. I understand it now. I thought that the multiple ifs will be checked at the same time. Like 2 goes in and 2 ifs check at the same time but only the first 1 passes then reduces it to 1. Then the while check fails and it stops.

Answer (score 1):

When input enters the while loop with the value 2, it enters the first if and when leaving the block its value is 1. Then it enters the 2 if and its value is set to 4. Then there is a new loop with values 4 2 1...

Answer (score 1):

Think of the situation when input is 2

`case 1. with 2 ifs  first if will make the input 1 and 2nd if will be executed and will make it again 4.`

`case 2 . with if else , once the input becomes 1 after first if it will come out of loop , and hence the result.`

Answer (score 1):

***Not an answer,*** but relevant for the Collatz sequence.

(The error being entering the first `if` changes `input` causing to enter
the second `if` if there would be no `else`.)

```
1 -> 1
odd n -> 3n+1 (even!)
even n -> n/2
```

As you can see odd n's could short cut taking two steps:

```
odd n ->-> (3n+1)/2
```

For math research this is a better sequence.

Then you can do without `else` entirely.

```
while (input != 1) {
    if (input % 2 == 1) {
        input = 3 * input + 1;
        System.out.print(input + ",");
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    /*if (input % 2 == 0)*/ {
        input /= 2;
        System.out.print(input + ",");
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The while loop will continue iterating until value of the variable, input is 1. In your sample example, when you enter input = 4, there will be infinite iterations (the loop will execute infinitely as per the conditions)

> Before while loop it prints **4** (the input)
>
> Iteration 1: input is 4. Enters while loop -> Enters 1st if as 4%2=0 and reassigns input to 4/2=2 -> Prints **2** -> Doesn't enter 2nd if as 2%2=0
>
> Iteration 2: input is 2. Enters while loop -> Enters 1st if as 2%2=0 and reassigns input to 2/2=1. Prints **1** -> Enters 2nd if as input=1 now and 1%2=1. -> Reassigns input = 3*1 + 1 = 4. Prints 4
>
> Then it again stats with 4. It continues infinitely printing **4 2 1 4 2 1 4 2 1** ...

```
while (input != 1) {
        //1st if
        if (input % 2 == 0) {
            input = input / 2;
            System.out.print(input + ",");
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        //2nd if
        if (input % 2 == 1) { // replace with else
            input = 3 * input + 1;
            System.out.print(input + ",");
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
}
```

Else statement executes only when the if condition fails. When you replace the 2nd if condition with a else statement, the program will not assign the input value to 4 again. Hence it will stop at **1**, printing **4 2 1**

Answer (score 1):

Each and every if condition is checked even though previous condition is passed or failed in multiple if statements. But in case of if-else block, if any one is passed others are skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while (input != 1) {
    if (input % 2 == 0) {
        input = input / 2;
        System.out.print(input + ",");
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    else { // replace with else
        input = 3 * input + 1;
        System.out.print(input + ",");
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

In your code:

```
while (input != 1) {
    if (input % 2 == 0) {
        input = input / 2;
        System.out.print(input + ",");
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    if (input % 2 == 1) { // replace with else
        input = 3 * input + 1;
        System.out.print(input + ",");
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

In your code if input is 2, then `input = input / 2;` this statement will make input 1. Next as `input % 2 == 1` will become true it will make input equal to 4(`input = 3 * input + 1;`) and the loop will not end. You should use else instead. Even the code is commented as `// replace with else`

Comment: Please add an explanation, code dumps with 0 explanation are not very helpful.

Comment: @vivek mangal That's actually my comment. I mean I used else to complete it but didn't fully understand why multiple ifs didn't work as well. But your explanation is very helpful. Thank you.